# Error no match for 'operator*'

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-precedence

I have a class that does decimal calculations. I have all the math operators overloaded. It works great for fairly simple calculations, but fails when I need to add parens. For example, both calculations in the following work and get the correct result:

```
myClass r, a = 100000, b = 2.5, c = 10, d = 30;
r = c / d * a * b;
r = (c / d) * a * b;
```

but if I change the calculation to `r = a * b * (c / d);` the compile fails with:

```
error: no match for ‘operator*’ in ‘myClass::operator*(myClass&)((* & b)) * myClass::operator/(myClass&)((* & d))’ in gcc 4.6.2.
```

I'm probably missing something simple, but can't find it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: We are missing something simple: The code with the operators.

Comment: I look into my crystal ball, and I see: your `operator*` or `operator/` either isn't `const`, or it lacks a `const` argument.  (note: this is a completely wild guess, and really we need the signatures of your operators to have any chance of doing anything besides making wild guesses)

Comment: Did you make sure that your `operator/` returns a `const reference` to the resulting instance?

Comment: Making sure you return a `const reference` to a local result seems like a strange thing to "make sure" of.

Comment: Typically, mathematical operators are implemented as functions which call member functions. For instance, a function `*` will call the member `*=`. This way the compiler can make better decisions regarding implicit type conversion. This might be related to your problem, but it is hard to tell with just your example.

Comment: Ah, it could be a `const` issue. I'll play with the code a bit and come back with the results.

Comment: Take a look at this PDF based on Scott Meyer's book: http://www.cs.duke.edu/csed/tapestry/howtoe.pdf. It shows the typical ways to implement operator overloading, including when to use `const`.

Comment: Yup, it was a couple of missing `const` qualifiers. I knew it was something simple ;-) @TravisParks, I'll take a look at that PDF. Will probably come in handy.

Comment: @JohnFrickson now that you have your answer, can post what the solution was, and then mark it as the solution?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As surmised by just about everybody, the problem was missing `const` qualifiers. Also a factor was that a copy was being returned instead of a reference.

The invalid code in question was like this:

```
myClass operator *= (myClass &num) { return Mul(num); }
myClass operator * (myClass &num) { return Mul(num); }
```

The corrected version:

```
myClass& operator *= (const myClass &num) { Mul(num); return *this; }
friend myClass operator * (const myClass &num1, const myClass &num2) { myClass tmp(num1) tmp.Mul(num2); return tmp; }
```